# ¿ Como puedo escribir en un archivo XLSX un array estático con columnas y filas aleatorio con un valor predeterminado de 7?

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, matrices

Muy bien, quiero insertar el número 7 en un archivo xslx y que las columnas y filas varien entre 3-7 y 2-8 para ello creo short de nf (numero de filas) y nc (numero de columnas), con esto creo la clase `setFilascolumnas` en donde implemento los aleatorio de la columnas y filas.

Más tarde en la clase `setMatriz` donde inicio la matriz y le doy el valor de 7

Y por ultimo en la clase `setDatos` recorro con un for todo y creo la hoja de trabajo junto con las celdas, asociandolo con nf y nc para que sean aleatorias y creo un `String aux` donde pongo la Matriz con nf y nc y le doy ese valor a las celdas, pero me da el siguiente error:

```
'Index 6 out of bounds for length 6'
```

Sé a que se refiere el error pero no se como solucionarlo
también pobre a insertar otro array estatico e igualarlo al anterior pero no se posible debido a que el otro esta vacio

dejo mi codigo aqui abajo, la clase escribir:

```
package e2.Ej2;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Escribir 
{   static short Matriz[][];
    public static short nf,nc;
    public static short mt;

    public static FileOutputStream Esc = null;
    
    public static XSSFWorkbook WK = null;
    public static XSSFSheet H1 = null;
    
    public static void setXSSFWorkbook()
    {   WK = new  XSSFWorkbook();
    }
    
    public static void setXSSFSheet()
    {   H1 = WK.createSheet("H1");
    }
    
    public static void setFilasColumnas()
    {   short minF = 3, maxF = 7;
        short minC = 2, maxC = 8;
        do
        {   nf = (short) (minF + (Math.random()*(maxF-minF)));
        }while(! (nf>=3) && (nf<=7));
        
        do
        {   nc = (short) (minC + (Math.random()*(maxC-minC)));
        }while(! (nc>=2) && (nc<=8));
    }
    
    public static void setMatriz()
    {   Matriz = new short[nf][nc];
         mt = 7;
    }
    
    public static void setDatos() 
    {   for (int f=3; f<nf; f++)
        {   XSSFRow filas = H1.createRow(f);
            for (int c=2; c<nc; c++)
            {   XSSFCell columnas = filas.createCell(c);
                //String txt = Matriz[nf][nc]+"";
                columnas.setCellValue(Matriz[nf][nc]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void setFlujo()
    {   try
        {   Esc = new FileOutputStream("MatrizAleatoria.xlsx");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void Enviar()
    {   try
        {   WK.write(Esc);
            Esc.flush();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void Cerrar()
    {   try
        {   Esc.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```